# Laravel - 419 Error when hitting POST route and CSRF token is expired

Tags: php, laravel, post, token

If I try to store a record in a simple Laravel project when the SESSION_LIFETIME has expired I get a 419 error. I have my CSRF fields working correctly but I only get this error if the token has expired. I would like to redirect to the login screen if the token is expired and I try to hit a post route. How can I do this? I can't find any information online about this issue.

Comment: Please, include some code. How are you making the request? What is your current set up? That is helpful to us so we can help you with your issue.

Comment: does this solves your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57095026/4258328 ?