# page expired 419 authentication system laravel livewire CSRF token mismatch

Tags: authentication, laravel-livewire, csrf-token

I use laravel with livewire. I encountered error 419 page expired

> throw new TokenMismatchException('CSRF token mismatch.')

I have a login and logout system with two different livewire component in the same page.
When I put:

```php
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

in the login component and:

```php
$request->session()->invalidate();
$request->session()->regenerateToken();
```

in the logout component, it started to throw this error. When I remove them there are no errors. Has anyone a solution?

EDIT:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;

class Nav extends Component
{
    public $currentPage=false;
    public function mount(){
        if(request()->route()->getName() === 'menu'){
            $this->currentPage = true;
        }
    }
    public function esci()
    { 
        
        Auth::logout();
        
        return redirect('/');
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.nav');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just don't do it

Comment: @Pippo in the documentation: We will access Laravel's authentication services via the Auth facade, so we'll need to make sure to import the Auth facade at the top of the class. Next, let's check out the attempt method. The attempt method is normally used to handle authentication attempts from your application's "login" form. If authentication is successful, you should regenerate the user's session to prevent session fixation.

Comment: Ok. Can you show your logout method?

Comment: @Pippo io use only a Auth::logout();

Comment: Ok, then post it here...

Comment: The `$request->session()->invalidate(); $request->session()->regenerateToken();` must be called after `Auth::logout();`. Look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094725/laravel-5-8-showing-419-page-expired-after-clicking-logout-from-an-already-cle) for some tips

Comment: @Pippo i already do that